# iframe on fullscreen is not working on ionic2

Tags: iframe, ionic2

My implementation of `iframe` is not working on `ionic 2` when clicked on 'fullscreen' mode. The button on `iframe` displays a white screen.

My `iframe` is the following:

```
<iframe *ngIf="homePagePlayvideoUrl" id="iframeTag" width="100%" height="200"
 [src]="homePagePlayvideoUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: did you solve this? I am having the same issue on Chrome and Android